# Python degrees defaulting to radians

Tags: python, trigonometry

I'm trying to print out the x,y value for a line with a certain degree which intersects a circle with a specified radius.

Lets say for example that the line is pointing straight up at 90 degrees.

```
import math

degree = 90
radius = 10
x = radius * math.cos(degree)
y = radius * math.sin(degree)

print(x,y)
```

This prints out *-4.480736161291701 8.939966636005579* but according to my calculator is supposed to print *0 10* on deg.

I have already tried adding math.radians and math.degrees before the degree var in the x = and y =, but it doesn't come out correctly any time I've tried. The link I found to the point where a line with degree intersects a circle is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260096/find-the-coordinates-of-a-point-on-a-circle), the sin/cos values are flipped 'tho for the x and y value in the solution.

Simply said, how would I make the 90 be in degrees instead of radians to get the correct x,y?

**EDIT:**

by adding math.radians:

```
x = radius * math.cos(math.radians(degree))
y = radius * math.sin(math.radians(degree))
```

it returned 6.123233995736766e-16 10.0

~~~

by adding math.degrees:

```
x = radius * math.cos(math.degrees(degree))
y = radius * math.sin(math.degrees(degree))
```

it returned -2.995153947555356 -9.540914674728182

Comment: You are probably looking to `polar coordinates to cartesian` and -4.4 and 8.9 should be correct.

Comment: Can you show how you tried to use `math.radians` and `math.degrees`?

Comment: Use `math.radians` to convert `degree` to radians before using it as an argument to `math.cos` or `math.sin`.

Answer (score 1):

All angles in most of the math libraries are in radians. The input to `math.cos` should be radians but you are passing in degrees.

```
import math

degree = 90
radius = 10
x = radius * math.cos(math.radians(degree))
y = radius * math.sin(math.radians(degree))
print x,y
>0, 10
```

`math.radians` is nothing more than doing `(pi * degree / 180 )`

Comment: When I run the exact code from you it prints:
6.123233995736766e-16 10.0,
since it is pointing straight up as of 90 deg, it should be returning 0 10 (x,y)

Comment: A float value only has 15 digits of accuracy. 6.1e-16 is 0.00000000000000061 ie about as close to 0.0 as it gets. For a sense of scale - this level of accuracy is enough to calculate the circumference of the solar system within 17mm == 3/4".

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can use `math.radians` to convert from degrees to radians. Note that it is not just Python that defaults to radians, it is usually the standard in mathematics to talk about angles in radians.

Although, in general, you can always use the conversion formula

```
radians = pi * degrees / 180
```

Comment: `2 * pi * degrees / 360 == pi * degrees / 180`, you don't need two multiply by 2, one less operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `math.radians(degree)` to convert to radians. All python's default trig functions work in radians. So your code becomes:

```
import math

degree = 90
radius = 10
x = radius * math.cos(math.radians(degree))
y = radius * math.sin(math.radians(degree))

print(x,y)
```

And this produces the correct result: 6.123233995736766e-16 10.0, with some odd floating point behavior you can fix with appropriate rounding.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a somewhat longer code, you can make your code work in degrees by putting in the following lines in the beginning:

```
from math import sin, cos, tan, asin, acos, atan
from math import radians as rad, degrees as deg

def s(x):
    return sin(rad(x))

def c(x):
    return cos(rad(x))

def t(x):
    return tan(rad(x))

def sa(x):
    return deg(asin(x))

def ca(x):
    return deg(acos(x))

def ta(x):
    return deg(atan(x))
```

Then, throughout your code, instead of typing `sin(90)` you would type `s(90)`, or for `arcsin(90)` you would type `sa(90)`. (I couldn't make the code word `as` for arcsine, since `as` is already a Python word)

Now, you would just type up your code as though it were in degrees and everything should work out fine.

Comment: What does `rad(x)` do? How is it defined?

Comment: @mistermiyagi I must have left out the line about importing radians. Thanks